# Why Nitroso tautomer is more stable than its oxime counterpart?

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

As I was looking for the answer of the question I found that it is explained using the Electronegativity difference concept.

That's correct but I am unable to prove the same through the bond energy data.

Can someone prove the same through it.

Comment: [Why is the oxime tautomer more stable than its corresponding nitroso isomer?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53220/why-is-the-oxime-tautomer-more-stable-than-its-corresponding-nitroso-isomer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the oxime tautomer more stable than its corresponding nitroso isomer?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53220/why-is-the-oxime-tautomer-more-stable-than-its-corresponding-nitroso-isomer)

Answer (score 4):

Counter example: Realistically, alkyl oximes are more stable than their nitroso counterparts. For example, computational studies has been shown that formaldehyde oxime is $\pu{15.8 kcal/mol}$ more stable than nitrosomethane when the aqueous solvation correction of $\pu{3.8 kcal/mol}$ is applied to the G2 energies. Unsolvated formaldehyde oxime is estimated to be $\pu{11.1 kcal/mol}$ more stable than nitrone (Ref.1). In solution chemistry, one of the difficulties association with synthesis of *C*-nitrosoalkanes is their likeliness to convert to the more stable corresponding oxime tautomer (Ref.2), apart from their high reactivity (Rings the bell?). You can find some $\Delta H_f(s)$, $\Delta H_f(l)$, and $\Delta H_f(g)$ of *C*-nitrosoalkanes in Ref.3. It is also noteworthy that $\ce{C-N}$ and $\ce{N-O}$ bond lengths are quite typical of oximes (overall values are $\pu{128.1 pm}$ and $\pu{141.6 pm}$, respectively), yet $\ce{N-O}$ in oximes are somewhat shorter than that of corresponding hydroxylamines. This indicates that some charge delocalization in oximes. However, the NMR evidence of *syn-anti* isomerization in oximes (e.g., *syn*-isome being the one with $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{OH}$ in the same side in acetoxime $\ce{CH3-CH=N-OH}$) confirms the predominance of oxime tautomer.

In closely relevant cases of *ortho*-nitrosonaphthols and acenaphthenequinonemonooxime, computational studies have been shown that the predominance of oxime form (Ref.4 and 5, respectively). For example, energy diagrams of 2-nitroso-1-naphthol and 1-nitroso-2-naphthol are illustrated in following diagrams:

[image: 2-nitroso-1-naphthol]

[image: 1-nitroso-2-naphthol]

---

References:

1. Judy A. Long, Nathan J. Harris, Koop Lammertsma, "Formaldehyde Oxime $\ce{<=>}$ Nitrosomethane Tautomerism," *J. Org. Chem.* **2001**, *66(20)*, 6762-6767 (https://doi.org/10.1021/jo010671v).
2. Brian G. Gowenlock, George B. Richter-Addo, "Preparations of C-Nitroso Compounds," *Chem. Rev.* **2004**, *104(7)*, 3315-3340 (https://doi.org/10.1021/cr030450k).
3. Suzanne W Slayden, Joel F. Liebman, "Chapter 3: The organic thermochemistry of hydroxylamines, oximes, hydroxamic Acids and their derivatives," In The Chemistry of Hydroxylamines, Oximes and Hydroxamic Acids, Part 1; Zvi Rappoport,Joel F. Liebman, Editors (Patai Series: The Chemistry of Functional Groups; Series Editor: Zvi Rappoport); John Wiley & Sons, Ltd.: Chichester, England, 2009, pp.53-83.
4. Galya Ivanova, Venelin Enchev, "Does tautomeric equilibrium exist in *ortho*-nitrosonaphthols?," *Chemical Physics* **2001**, *264(3)*, 235-244 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0301-0104(01)00245-2).
5. V. Enchev, G. Ivanova, A. Ugrinov, G. D. Neykov, "Tautomeric and conformational equilibrium of acenaphthenequinonemonooxime," *Journal of Molecular Structure* **1999**, *508(1-3)*, 149-161 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-2860(99)00008-3).