# Bond strength and length of HF and H2O

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

I know that acidity of an acid increases across a period (with electronegativity increase of the atom bonded to hydrogen) and hence $\ce{HF}$ is more acidic than $\ce{H2O}$ or $\ce{NH3}$. But the reason I learnt it is this way, is that difference in electronegativities of the atoms increases and hence bond becomes more polar and weaker (hence easier to donate a proton).

But shouldn't bond strength increase with difference in electronegativities? Also bond length of $\ce{HF}$ is shorter than that of $\ce{H2O}$ ($\pu{92 pm}$ vs $\pu{96 pm}$) and bond enthalpy of $\ce{HF}$ is $\pu{565kJ/mol}$ as opposed to $\pu{490kJ/mol}$ of water. Isn't this contradictory? Why is $\ce{HF}$ still more acidic than $\ce{H2O}$?
Is it because  the conjugate base of $\ce{HF}$ is highly solvated and more stable in an aqueous solution?  Is there not a direct correlation between ease of bond dissociation and acidity?

P.S.: I understand the acidic trend down the group (stability of conjugate base increases and since the halogen atom becomes bigger, resulting in weaker bonds).

Comment: see this [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39711/electronegativity-and-how-it-relates-to-bond-strength) . Did you get your answer?

Comment: Your welcome :-)